# Submit HTML Form - Prevent Redirect and capture JSON response

Tags: html, forms

I am successfully submitting an HTML form to my backend, however I want to prevent the redirection and read the JSON message returned by the backend.
So far I only have the usual HTML form with a submit button.

UPDATE (To fix CORS Error):
Added the following three lines before `RewriteEngine On` in the .htaccess file of my backend:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using an onclick function for the submit button. Instead of using 'submit' button, use 'button' button.

Comment: @SureshMSidy, I haven't added Javascript yet... Instead I have a ```button type="submit"``` and action and method in the form

Comment: The examples I've seen use AJAX usually or Javascript however none seem to work as expected.

Comment: So you are submitting the complete HTML form to your server expecting that server gives you response. Instead, use Ajax with async - true. Or False

Comment: The server gives me a response, infact I am redirected to a page with the JSON message. I want to prevent the redirection and instead get the JSON message and show it within the same webpage.

Comment: Could you guide me towards a tutorial please?

Comment: Check this - https://formkeep.com/guides/submit-form-with-ajax

Comment: Otherwise try using 'button' button and do an onclick js function. From function do ajax and then when you got the result submit the form from js-itself.

Comment: @SureshMSidy understood, when using AJAX/JS - I keep getting the following error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'backend-url' from origin 'w3schools.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @LukeGalea where you able to solve the issue? I have similar problem keep redirecting me to the json message